# How to load a Firefox addon on page load?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm using

`chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){ });`

on chrome, but it dos not work on Firefox, I have seen

`browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener[, extraParameters])`

on Firefox documentation, but I'm not sure how to use it, can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

**chrome & browser API**

- You can use both `chrome.*` and `browser.*` API in Firefox.
- `chrome.*` returns a callback function (although that is due to change to support Promise in [manifest v3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/)).
- `browser.*` returns a Promise.

In case of `*.addListene()`, they always return a callback function.

Therefore, in Firefox the following are similar (and you can use either).

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){ 
  // do something
});


browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){ 
  // do something
});
```

`browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()` in Firefox can also have *optional extraParameters* but from your example it seems you might not need it.

ref:
[chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/)
[browser.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated)